# How to correctly update a dependency in a .bzl file?

Tags: bazel

I want to make modifications to a project I cloned, which uses bazel.
The project has a native.git_repository dependency on another bazel based project, which is located in `github`. I need to make changes in that dependency project as well.
What is the best way to change the `bazel` file to depend on the updated project? I tried using native.local_repository and point to my local cloned repository, but `bazel` failed:

> ERROR: error loading package '': Encountered error while reading extension file 'bazel/repositories.bzl': no such package '@xxxxxxxxx//bazel': /build/tmp/_bazel_bazel/436badd4919a15958fa3800a4e21074a/external/xxxxxxxxx must be an existing directory

Did my solution correct, or is there a better solution?
Why did it fail?

Comment: Your approach sounds correct though the implementation might have a bug. Can you share a bit more details? Mainly relevant parts of the WORKSPCE file and at least one example of how targets depend on the external workspace

Comment: TalR's note from bazel-discuss: 

original code:
`native.git_repository(
        name = "envoy_api",
        remote = REPO_LOCATIONS["envoy_api"],
        commit = "9be6aff6da46e024af56cce20cb5d5d3184f19c5",
    )`

new code:

 `native.local_repository(
         name = "envoy_api",
         path = "/home/talis/data-plane-api",
    )`

Comment: What does `ls -d /home/talis/data-plane-api` says? Can you try to do `bazel clean --expunge` then rebuild? What does `ls -l /build/tmp/_bazel_bazel/436badd4919a15958fa3800a4e21074a/external/xxxxxxxxx` says? (I guess the `xxxxxxx` are pointing to data-plane-api?

Comment: Thanks for catching me here as well :). /home/talis/data-plane-api exists and ls -l /build/tmp/_bazel_bazel/436badd4919a15958fa3800a4e21074a/ext‌​ernal/data-plane-api doesn't. I tried cleaning, did not help.

Comment: looking again, there is /home/talis/build/tmp/_bazel_bazel/436badd4919a15958fa3800a4e21074a/external/envoy_api - does it lead to the root cause? seems something is not defined correctly for bazel

Comment: What does `ls -d  /home/talis/build/tmp/_bazel_bazel/436badd4919a15958fa3800a4‌​e21074a/external/env‌​oy_api` returns? (not just asking for the existence of the directory, I need to see the returns of the ls command), same for /home/talis/data-plane-api.

Comment: I just realized the problem. I am compiling inside a Docker... so it does not know absolute path to my local. I mounted the local directory and it is solved. Thanks!